# Http post losing data when input contains base64 image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post, base64

I am submitting a number of resized base64 images in hidden inputs. Basically after a certain point the $_POST object loses the rest of the data. I am encoding the urls in encodeURICompenent and this appears to be working without checking the complete urls, they have escaped characters.

I have tried different images and it always seems to be at a certain point e.g. image 9 would have incomplete string.

I also changed the post size limit to 1048576000 bytes and the post is 918882 (think its in bytes, couldnt be mbs...) using  $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] which equals 1135958 so i dont think its size related. Post ex time is 60secs...

I have the javascript below that populates the hidden input but ***is there anything else to check?*** ( i am testing on chrome )

```
jQuery.when( readFile(value) ).done(function(value) {

        resizeBase64Img(value, 300, 200).done(function(newImg){

             var newurl = encodeURIComponent(newImg[0].src)

 jQuery('#selectedimages').append('<input type="hidden"  name="images['+name.name+']" id="i'+i+'" value="'+newurl+'"/>');

        });

    });//end when
```

Comment: If it's the time, and you can have your script actually execute, you can change the time limit with `set_time_limit(xx)`

Comment: hi, no its not time either, it returns in a few seconds incomplete. i have it set in php.ini to 60s